# How do I get the number of frames from a gif file in python 3.8.6?

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I am trying to load a gif out of a folder of gifs, which is selected by a number on a txt document. It is selecting the correct one, but I am not sure how to get the number of frames from the selected gif.
Here is the code so far:

```
    from tkinter import *
    from PIL import Image, ImageTk
    from time import sleep
    import os

    root = Tk()
    root.title("displaygif")
    root.geometry("404x484")

    with open('wantedgif/wantedgif.txt') as wantedgif:        #This is the file where the ID for the gif is
        gifID = wantedgif.readline(3)
        print (gifID)

    line_number = 0
    with open("CodeRef/gifIDList.txt", 'r') as read_obj:    #This is the file that has the ID and what 
                                                             the gif names are, under there respective ID
        for line in read_obj:
            line_number += 1
                if gifID in line:
                line_number -= 1
                gif = read_obj.readlines()
                print(gif[line_number])                     #This all seems to work fine

    im = Image.open('gif/' + gif[line_number].strip() + '.gif')    #Opens the gif using the gif name
```

I am not sure how to count the number of frames in the gif, and how to display it either. I have searched for a few hours, but cannot find anything that works. It would be preferable to not import anything else, but it doesn't really matter. Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the code you posted is actually basically unrelated to your actual question?

Comment: How is that so?

Comment: You are reading a bunch of labels from text files; these operations are completely unrelated to the problem you are asking about.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `im.n_frames` to get the number of frames inside the GIF image.